# WHERE...LIMIT much slower than WHERE...ORDER BY...LIMIT in MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-5.5

I'm using MySQL 5.5 (but i see the same behavior on 5.7)

Here is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `so_table` (
  `p` char(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `c1` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
  `c3` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `c4` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`p`),
  INDEX `so_table_index_1` (`c1`,`c2`),
  INDEX `so_table_index_2` (`c4`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8
```

The table contains around 2 million rows. The query below is considered a slow query and sometimes takes 20 seconds to execute:

`SELECT p, c1 FROM so_table WHERE c1 IS NOT NULL AND c3 = 1 AND c4 < 195217615 LIMIT 100;`

Running `EXPLAIN` on the query above returns the following:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | so_table | NULL | range | so_table_index_1,so_table_index_2 | so_table_index_1 | 5 | NULL | 1,281,736 | Using index condition; Using where |

I was reading about optimizing LIMIT and it seems that adding ORDER BY makes things better, so the following query indeed has a better execution plan (i haven't tried it on the real data though)

`SELECT p, c1 FROM so_table WHERE c1 IS NOT NULL AND c3 = 1 AND c4 < 203322189 ORDER BY p ASC LIMIT 100;`

And `EXPLAIN` shows the following:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | so_table | NULL | index | so_table_index_1,so_table_index_2 | PRIMARY | 48 | NULL | 428 | Using index condition; Using where |

So it seems that this query is going to be faster. My guess is that `ORDER BY` forces the optimizer to use the primary index which is unique and maybe this helps the optimizer decide to not actually run through all rows. I was [reading](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/where-optimization.html) [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/range-optimization.html#range-access-single-part) [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html), but i couldn't figure out if my theory is right or what's the real reason is.

Comment: What happens if you add an index on c3, c4, c1?

Answer (score 1):

By adding the `ORDER BY` clause to your query, it resulted in the **query optimizer** choosing a different **execution plan** that uses the index to seek out the rows (which was a lot less rows to seek) as opposed to scanning the range of a lot more rows in your first query.

This isn't a guarantee that `ORDER BY` will always cause this to happen, but in this case it influenced the **query optimizer** to choose a different operation that happened to be more efficient (likely because the index it used is already sorted on the field you're ordering by).

Comment: I understand that ORDER BY forced the usage of a particular index in this case. What I don’t understand is why so many rows need to be scanned. The first execution path was ‘range’ which means it’s already going to use an index.

Comment: I believe because it's using the index on `c4` in the first query because of your predicate `c4 < 195217615` which results a large range scan before the other predicates filter down the results.

Comment: @buskila - EXPLAIN's "Rows" are estimated.  In some cases they are reasonably accurate, in some cases, they are terribly far off.  In particular, `EXPLAIN` usually ignores `LIMIT` which making an estimate.